# Creating a model which weights are the sum of weights of 2 different neural networks

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network, mnist, transfer-learning

I am doing an experiment of transfer learning.
I trained 2 CNNs that have exactly the same structure, one for MNIST and one for SVHN.
I obtained the parameters (weights  and bias) of the 2 models.
Now, I want to combine (sum, or other operations) these weights. A thing like this:

```
modelMNIST.parameters()
modelSVHN.parameters()

#now the new model
model3 = MyCNN(1)
model3.parameters = modelMNIST.parameters()+modelSVHN.parameters()
```

If I do in this way, I obtain this error:
`SyntaxError: can't assign to function call`

And in this way:

```
model3.block_1[0].weight = modelMNIST.block_1[0].weight + modelSVHN.block_1[0].weight
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: cannot assign 'torch.cuda.FloatTensor' as parameter 'weight' (torch.nn.Parameter or None expected)
```

Is there any way to combine weights of different models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is this:

```
class VGG16SUM(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self, model1, model2, num_classes):
        super(VGG16SUM, self).__init__()

        # calculate same padding:
        # (w - k + 2*p)/s + 1 = o
        # => p = (s(o-1) - w + k)/2

        self.block_1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1,
                      out_channels=64,
                      kernel_size=(3, 3),
                      stride=(1, 1),
                      # (1(32-1)- 32 + 3)/2 = 1
                      padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64,
                      out_channels=64,
                      kernel_size=(3, 3),
                      stride=(1, 1),
                      padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2),
                         stride=(2, 2))
        )

        self.block_2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64,
                      out_channels=128,
                      kernel_size=(3, 3),
                      stride=(1, 1),
                      padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=128,
                      out_channels=128,
                      kernel_size=(3, 3),
                      stride=(1, 1),
                      padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2),
                         stride=(2, 2))
        )
        
        self.block_3 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=128,
                      out_channels=256,
                      kernel_size=(3, 3),
                      stride=(1, 1),
                      padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256,
                      out_channels=256,
                      kernel_size=(3, 3),
                      stride=(1, 1),
                      padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256,
                      out_channels=256,
                      kernel_size=(3, 3),
                      stride=(1, 1),
                      padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2),
                         stride=(2, 2))
        )

        self.block_4 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256,
                      out_channels=512,
                      kernel_size=(3, 3),
                      stride=(1, 1),
                      padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(512),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=512,
                      out_channels=512,
                      kernel_size=(3, 3),
                      stride=(1, 1),
                      padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(512),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=512,
                      out_channels=512,
                      kernel_size=(3, 3),
                      stride=(1, 1),
                      padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(512),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2),
                         stride=(2, 2))
        ) 


        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(2048, 4096),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Dropout(p=0.25),
            nn.Linear(4096, 4096),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Dropout(p=0.25),
            nn.Linear(4096, num_classes),
        )

        for p_out, p_in1, p_in2 in zip(self.parameters(), model1.parameters(), model2.parameters()):
            p_out.data = nn.Parameter(p_in1 +p_in2);

    def forward(self, x):

        x = self.block_1(x)
        x = self.block_2(x)
        x = self.block_3(x)
        x = self.block_4(x)
        # x = self.avgpool(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = self.classifier(x)
        return x
        #logits = self.classifier(x)
        #probas = F.softmax(logits, dim=1)
        # probas = nn.Softmax(logits)
        #return probas
        # return logits
```

It works!!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to update the `.data` attribute of the parameter. `Parameter` is not FloatTensor and hence the error.

Since the two networks are identical you can use the below code to update the weights.

```
for param1, param2 in zip(modelMNIST.parameters(), modelSVHN.parameters()):
     param1.data += param2.data
```

Comment: Thanks. I have to write it after instantiating the new model? Like `model3 = VGG16(1)` and then modifying your code in this way: `for param1, param2, param3 in zip(modelMNIST.parameters(), modelSVHN.parameters(), model3.parameters()):
     param3.data = param1.data + param2.data`

Comment: Do you think is good a solution like this?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.

Comment: I found another way that works. Thank you again

Comment: ah ok, sure! You do not need `nn.Parameter` in your solution though.